# How to use rails update method for multiple object with collection

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am trying to update multiple objects with rails update method with update collection object as following codes:(couldn't really find the collection method)

```
def update

      @reiew = Review.find(reivew_params)
       review.update!(reivew_params)

        if @reivews.update(reivew_params)
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to reivew_path}
      end
    else
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html { notice: 'saved errors'}
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Isn't update_all available for your Rails version?

Comment: There seem to be some typos in your code (`reivews`, ...)

Comment: You tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails-3`. If that is indeed the version you use (if you can, don't! use Rails 5.x), it would be helpful to mention that in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

In "modern" Rails versions (apparently since 3.0) you can use

`update_all` (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)

like this:

`Review.where(id: [2,5,10]).update_all(reviews_params)`

. That code would update the `Reviews` with id 2, 5 and 10.